# Default Connection to master DB

Tags: sql-server, connection

Our application hosted in multitier environment. When the App servers create a connection to the SQL Server it opens the connection on its default database (let's say xyz) but when the Data Servers who use the same connection string opens connection on default database and as well as master database.

Is there any reason for that. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure they are using the same connection string? If they were using different logins, they could have different default databases.

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection properties on your data server. The driver (OLEDB, ODBC, ADO.NET) all should have a capability of identifying the default database that they connect to. My guess is that the data server driver connects by default to the master database because of the driver property.